# How to fetch a query with SHOW DATABASE LIKE statement?

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

I want to fetch some databases according to a specific name.

I have:

```
$sql="SHOW DATABASES LIKE `'%backup%'`";
$query=mysql_query($sql,$connect);
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
```

I need to fetch the databases in an array according to a specific name,but it gives me an error:

```
mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
```

**Any idea how to do this?(And yes i know mysql is deprecated but i have to use it)**

Comment: Change your query to `SHOW DATABASES LIKE '%backup%'`, just remove `

Answer (score 4):

here we go, its tested and working, but i will suggest you to use PDO, since **mysql_*** api is deprecated.

```
$sql="SHOW DATABASES LIKE '%backup%'";
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$query=mysql_query($sql,$connect) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
 echo $row[0]."<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have tested it
**use:**
 `SHOW DATABASES LIKE '%backup%'`

Comment: i tested it too,and still isnt working,and your answer isnt different of what i have tried,as you can see above

Comment: @Memphistoles, you're wrong, you tried with `, remove it and the query will work

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered just listing all databases, then iterating through all results, matching them via regex/stripos and appending them into an array?

```
$sql="SHOW DATABASES";
$query=mysql_query($sql,$connect);

while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
$var = preg_match("/backup/", $row['database'])
# Do whatever - append to array, echo, etc
}
```

Comment: lets say i have one or more database named auth_backup-2014,auth1_backup_2014,etc  among other db auth,auth1,etc ,and i want to extract the dbs from the array,that contains the extension backup,how i am going to do that with preg_match ??

Comment: Preg_match will attempt to match a string pattern against the string you provide (In this case, the database names). Upon finding a match, it will do what you tell it to do - you could append $var into an array, echo it, etc, as each while loop will overwrite the last value. [This might help a bit more](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php). It also allows the use of wildcards, patterns etc, but your case is much more simple. The pattern I provided should work regardless of the location of "backup" in the string. [This might also help](http://lzone.de/PHP%20preg_match%20Examples)

Comment: aham,great,by the way "backup" has a prefix and a sufix , in this care should i use % in pregmatch ??

Comment: No, /backup/ should be fine - I used a similar pattern earlier trawling a CSV file and had no issues. You could try '/backup/i' if you have issues with upper/lowercase mixtures though

Comment: nah,if this syntax works for something like : _backup- ,then it's alright

Comment: Try it and let me know - it should be fine

Comment: ,seems like is not working for an array...i mean i need to return the strings containing the pattern 'backup',from an array,and also to insert them into a different array

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**
use `mysql_select_db` to select databases.see here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php

or you can use `mysql_list_dbs` but the problem is it will give all database. so using some loop you have to use your like operator to get what you want. see this:http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-dbs.php

Comment: i want to fetch the databases with a specific name,so i can delete them all,so i need to work with more db,while mysql_select_db works just with one